# How to DRY up a PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, count, sql-order-by

I don't often write raw SQL but in doing so recently I can't help but think that this query is not very DRY. Is there a way to tighten this up?

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) as "Users", DATE_TRUNC('day', created_at) AS "Date"
FROM
  users
WHERE created_at > now() - interval '1 year'
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', created_at)
ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('day', created_at);
```

Currently this returns:

```
Users  Date
175    2019-10-01 00:00:00
54     2019-10-02 00:00:00
142    2019-10-03 00:00:00
...
```

What I want is to group all new Users by `created_at` date but only go back a year (or whatever arbitrary date we choose). Not sure `DATE_TRUNC` is best way to approach this. More sure that repeating it 3 times is probably not.

Answer (score 3):

You can use column aliases in a `group by` and `order by`.

```
SELECT
  count(*) as "Users",
  date_trunc('day', created_at) AS "Date"
FROM
  users
WHERE
  created_at > now() - interval '1 year'
GROUP BY "Date"
ORDER BY "Date"
```

Answer (score 2):

`date_trunc()` is the right tool to truncate a timestamp to a date. An alternative is to cast. As for the `group by` and `order by` clauses, you can use positional parameters or column aliases.

So:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt_users, created_at::date AS created_date
FROM users
WHERE created_at > current_date - interval '1 year'
GROUP BY created_date  -- or ORDER BY 2
ORDER BY created_date  -- or ORDER BY 2
```

Notes:

- I adjusted the `where` clause so it filters on *entire* days
- I used unquoted identifiers; quoting the identifiers is not DRY to start with, and it also makes them case-sensitive